# How to filter selected columns in snowflake from csv

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we have CSV file with comma delimiter and the file is loaded in pre staging table (Totally 50 columns) , while we try to insert into another table (30 columns) , 20 columns are not required to insert into the table , we are getting conflict rows match

please suggest me, how to do using snowflake stored procedure or java script .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Totally 50 columns) , while we try to insert into another table (30 columns) , 20 columns are not required to insert into the table , we are getting conflict rows match

`Insert into select` allows to **explicitly** define column list:

```
INSERT INTO target_table(col1, col2, ..., col30)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., col30
FROM pre_staging_table
```

Comment: It's from a stage with a CSV file, so it would be $1, $2, $3... Skipping the ones not needed and setting the ordinal positions according to the target table.